# How to perform vector based function on all row values of a dataframe

Tags: r

I am new to R and I have this problem where I am trying to figure out how can I perform a vector based function on all the values in a row in a dataframe and implement that on the whole dataframe.

To elaborate, my dataframe is following

```
> Column1<-c("red","blue")#creating column1
> Column2<-c("green","white")#creating column2
> Column3<-c("aqua","magenta")#creating column3
> df_1<-data.frame(Column1, Column2, Column3)#creating data frame
> df_1
```

which produces following

```
| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 |
|---------|---------|---------|
| red     | green   | aqua    |
| blue    | white   | magenta |
```

Now, I want to run a combn on each of the row of this dataframe.
I know how to run combn on a single vector like following

```
> x1<-combn(c("red","green","aqua"),2)
> x2<-combn(c("blue","white","magenta"),2)
```

which gives me this
x1

```
| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 |
|---------|---------|---------|
| red     | red     | green   |
| green   | aqua    | aqua    |
```

x2

```
| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 |
|---------|---------|---------|
| blue    | blue    | white   |
| white   | magenta | magenta |
```

Now all I want to do is to run the combn on the rows of the previously created df_1 in such a way so that it gives me the following output in a dataframe

```
| Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Result  | CAT     |
|---------|---------|---------|---------|---------|
| red     | green   | aqua    | red     | Result1 |
| red     | green   | aqua    | green   | Result1 |
| red     | green   | aqua    | red     | Result2 |
| red     | green   | aqua    | aqua    | Result2 |
| red     | green   | aqua    | green   | Result3 |
| red     | green   | aqua    | aqua    | Result3 |
| blue    | white   | magenta | blue    | Result1 |
| blue    | white   | magenta | white   | Result1 |
| blue    | white   | magenta | blue    | Result2 |
| blue    | white   | magenta | magenta | Result2 |
| blue    | white   | magenta | white   | Result3 |
| blue    | white   | magenta | magenta | Result3 |
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There might be a more sophisticated solution to this, but this produces
the results you are asking for.

Prepare Data

```r
df_1 <- structure(list(Column1 = c("red", "blue"), 
                       Column2 = c("green","white"), 
                       Column3 = c("aqua", "magenta")), 
                  class = "data.frame",
                  row.names = c(NA, 2L))
```

Use `apply()` to go through all rows (`MARGIN = 1`), apply `FUN = combn` to every
row, with the additional argument `2` as the `m` argument to combn.

```r
res1 <- apply(X = df_1, MARGIN = 1, FUN = combn, 2)
res1
#>      1       2        
#> [1,] "red"   "blue"   
#> [2,] "green" "white"  
#> [3,] "red"   "blue"   
#> [4,] "aqua"  "magenta"
#> [5,] "green" "white"  
#> [6,] "aqua"  "magenta"
```

Now we have the combinations you are looking for, but we still need to
get them into the format you describe:

```r
res2 <-
  rbind(data.frame(df_1[1, ], Result = res1[, 1]),
        data.frame(df_1[2, ], Result = res1[, 2]))
#> Warning in data.frame(df_1[1, ], Result = res1[, 1]): row names were found from
#> a short variable and have been discarded
#> Warning in data.frame(df_1[2, ], Result = res1[, 2]): row names were found from
#> a short variable and have been discarded
res2$CAT <- paste0("Result", rep(1:3, each = 2))   
res2
#>    Column1 Column2 Column3  Result     CAT
#> 1      red   green    aqua     red Result1
#> 2      red   green    aqua   green Result1
#> 3      red   green    aqua     red Result2
#> 4      red   green    aqua    aqua Result2
#> 5      red   green    aqua   green Result3
#> 6      red   green    aqua    aqua Result3
#> 7     blue   white magenta    blue Result1
#> 8     blue   white magenta   white Result1
#> 9     blue   white magenta    blue Result2
#> 10    blue   white magenta magenta Result2
#> 11    blue   white magenta   white Result3
#> 12    blue   white magenta magenta Result3
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>